# Codeigniter Anchor not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using Windows 7 to develop on.

I am having trouble with my anchors in codeigniter. I get an error.

```
The requested URL /mysite/contact was not found on this server.
```

If i add index.php to my anchor it works.

```
<?php echo anchor('index.php/contact', 'Contact Us', 'title="Contact"');?>
```

If I remove the `index.php` part then I get the above error.

I am using WAMP have rewrite module enabled. In my config I have the following.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite';
```

And

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And lastly here is my .haccess I am using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe its something with upper/lowercase characters?

Comment: Can you show us controller part for `contact`?

Comment: I got this working. I had the .htaccess file in my application folder and not at the root of the domain. Thanks

Comment: You can answer own question and accept it @james.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had the .htaccess file in my application folder and not at the root of the site.